# How does Azure DocumentDB scale? And do I need to worry about it?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I've got an application that's outgrowing SQL Azure - at the price I'm willing to pay, at any rate - and I'm interested in investigating Azure DocumentDB. The preview clearly has distinct scalability limits (as described [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-limits/), for instance), but I think I could probably get away with those for the preview period, provided I'm using it correctly.

So here's the question I've got. How do I need to design my application to take advantage of the built-in scalability of the Azure DocumentDB? For instance, I know that with Azure Table Storage - that cheap but <strike>awful</strike> highly limited alternative - you need to structure all your data in a two-step hierarchy: PartitionKey and RowKey. Provided you do that (which is nigh well impossible in a real-world application), ATS (as I understand it) moves partitions around behind the scenes, from machine to machine, so that you get near-infinite scalability. Awesome, and you never have to think about it.

Scaling out with SQL Server is obviously much more complicated - you need to design your own sharding system, deal with figuring out which server the shard in question sits on, and so forth. Possible, and done right quite scalable, but complex and painful.

So how does scalability work with DocumentDB? It promises arbitrary scalability, but how does the storage engine work behind the scenes? I see that it has "Databases", and each database can have some number of "Collections", and so forth. But how does its arbitrary scalability map to these other concepts? If I have a SQL table that contains hundreds of millions of rows, am I going to get the scalability I need if I put all this data into one collection? Or do I need to manually spread it across multiple collections, sharded somehow? Or across multiple DB's? Or is DocumentDB somehow smart enough to coalesce queries in a performant way from across multiple machines, without me having to think about any of it? Or...?

I've been looking around, and haven't yet found any guidance on how to approach this. Very interested in what other people have found or what MS recommends.

Comment: Not sure why you decided to color your question with subjective and negative commentary ("Table Storage - that cheap but awful alternative"). Azure Table Storage is a key/value NoSQL store, completely different from SQL Server (relational) or DocumentDB (document).

Comment: I agree the negative commentary isn't strictly necessary, but I've found ATS to be missing critical features found in other key-value store databases - see http://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage, for instance. If a widely-promoted technology is all-but-unusable, it doesn't seem out-of-bounds to mention that.

Comment: There are many who find it very usable. This is why it's best to leave this type of color commentary out of your question.

Comment: We can probably agree to disagree :-). (There are some limited scenarios where I've found ATS to be helpful.) In the meantime, since I see you're an Azure architect, any suggestions on how to go about structuring data in DocumentDB to ensure scalability?

Comment: Azure Table Storage does not provide automatic infinite scale, either. The throughput limit (based on 1K size messages) for a single partition is only 2,000 messages per second. The aggregate limit for an entire storage account is only 20,000. Yes, it balances I/O, but automatic scale? No.

Comment: BTW, I'll just say that looking back on this, my negative opinions about ATS have been well justified. Even MS can't be bothered to improve it. It's been years since any significant updates. I would strongly caution against using ATS for any new apps, even if your app is the sort of niche app that needs (and only needs) what ATS offers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update: As of April 2016, DocumentDB has introduced the concept of a [partitioned collection](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-partition-data/) which allows you scale-out and take advantage of server-side partitioning.**

A single DocumentDB database can scale practically to an unlimited amount of document storage partitioned by collections (in other words, you can scale out by adding more collections).

Each collection provides 10 GB of storage, and an variable amount of throughput (based on performance level). A collection also provides the scope for document storage and query execution; and is also the transaction domain for all the documents contained within it.

Source: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-manage/

Here's a [link to a blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/documentdb/archive/2014/12/03/scaling-a-multi-tenant-application-with-azure-documentdb.aspx) I wrote on scaling and partitioning data for a multi-tenant application on DocumentDB.

Comment: correct. DocumentDB doesn't do any magic around auto sharding and query coalescing, yet. Today you have to handle sharding across collections yourself.

Comment: Got it. In other words, I can think of a collection as the maximum unit of scalability. If I know I'm going to need a particular striation of data access to scale horizontally, I'm going to have to split it manually across multiple collections. Kind of like self-sharding in SQL Server (albeit a bit easier, since there's no schema to maintain). No magic there yet.

Comment: Does that mean the collection is your scalability unit,  like what a partition is for azure table storage? In other words, if all my documents are within one collection, does that mean I don't scale beyond one server node?

Comment: Kind of. You're correct that collections are the scalability unit and you can think of them as partitions. To scale beyond 10gb, you will want to partition your data across collections - and write some logic to route to the correct partition or fan-out for queries. Technically, collections do not belong to a single server node - there are replicas that ensure quorum and boost read throughput working behind the scenes.

Comment: They also limit you to 3 collections per capacity unit.

Comment: Yes, and you can have 50 capacity units per database account. Note that the concept of a "capacity unit" will be going away in favor of working directly w/ collections with the GA launch in April.

Comment: @aliuy Thanks - can you point me to a resource that explains this? Will we still be limited, collections-wise? Currently, the limit is 3 collections per CU...without CU,  what will the limit be? (Also, the limit of 2,000,000 permissions seems absurdly low, unless all we ever use for access control is the collection, at which point you don't need, and cannot have, 2,000,000)

Comment: The limit on collections hasn't set in stone yet - but there will likely be a soft limit of 100 collections per database account. There will be more resources published as the GA launch draws closer. You can contact support or me (andrl {at} microsoft.com) to raise the collection limit for you.

Comment: Another thing to point out is that there will be new adjustable performance tiers set at a collection level, to be introduced during the GA launch. There are some details on this published here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-performance-levels/

Answer (score 3):

With the latest version of DocumentDB, things have changed. There is still the 10GB limit per collection but in the past, it was up to you to figure out how to split up your data into multiple collections to avoid hitting the 10 GB limit.

Instead, you can now, specify a partition key and DocumentDB now handles the partitioning for you e.g. If you have log data, you may want to partition the data on the date value in your JSON document, so that each day a new partition is created.

Answer (score 0):

You can fan out queries like this - http://stuartmcleantech.blogspot.co.uk/2016/03/scalable-querying-multiple-azure.html